# проблемы с запросами в vk android

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Не могу понять как делать правильно делать запросы в ВКонтакте.

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.audio().add(VKParameters.from("owner_id",  "audio_id", ID_list.get(contex_menu_position)));
```

`owner_id` - если не указывать то, `id` будет браться по-умолчанию, т.е. мой.
`ID_list` - `ArrayList<Integer>` который хранит `id` песен.

В результате получаю "VKError (API errorVKError (code: 100; ; One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: audio_id is undefined))", уже перепробовал много комбинаций, толку - 0.

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему. Пришлось в каждый запрос указывать `owner_id`, заработало только так, вот код, может кому пригодится

```
VKRequest requestAdd = VKApi.audio().add(VKParameters.from("owner_id",owner_ID.get(contex_menu_position),  "audio_id", ID_list.get(contex_menu_position)));
```